# multiple sidepanels transition javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple sidepanels linked to multiple buttons on my page.

Basically, when I click one button one panel should open and when I click the second button, the first panel should close and second panel should be opened.

I have 9 such panels.

[image]

Currently using jQuery to achieve it also this is how I used the sidepanel https://codyhouse.co/demo/slide-in-panel/index.html

If anyone can help it would be great.

```
 <div class="cd-panel from-right"> 
                <header class="cd-panel-header">
                    <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>
                </header>
                <div class="cd-panel-container">
Content
        </div>
    </div>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible');
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Button

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn" id="nvv-i"></i>
```

Comment: We will need to see some code. Specifically the html for the panels and the javascript/jquery that opens them.

Comment: why not re-use the same panel and set the content depending on the button?

Comment: Yea sure, currently I have re-used the same panel and set the content. But when I click each of the button, all the sidepanels remain opened. They do not close automatically. @cycopepe

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just to add:
I have panels named as 
1. cd-panel
2. cd-panel-1
3. cd-panel-2 etc

buttons controlling them are
1. cd-btn
2. cd-btn-1
3. cd-btn-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the other sidepanels classes to remove class $('.cd-panel-a').removeClass('is-visible');

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible');
        $('.cd-panel-a').removeClass('is-visible');     
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with some jQuery, I've tried to write the below to be as dynamic as possible, utilising the data-* attribute.

I've taken the code from the article you provided, but looks like some of the CSS is missing from that article..

**Edit: Using the code you've provided...**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //open the lateral panel
  $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event) {
   // close any previously opened panels
   $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
  
   // get the number of the panel to show from the data-panel attribute on the button
   var panelToShow = $(this).data('panel');
  
    event.preventDefault();
    // add the is-visible class to the panel with the data-panel attribute value matching that of the button
    $('.cd-panel[data-panel="' + panelToShow + '"]').addClass('is-visible');
  });
  //close the lateral panel
  $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close')) {
      $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cd-panel {
  visibility: hidden
}

.is-visible {
  visibility: visible
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cd-panel from-right" data-panel="1">
  <header class="cd-panel-header">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>
  </header>
  <div class="cd-panel-container">
    Panel 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cd-panel from-right" data-panel="2">
  <header class="cd-panel-header">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>
  </header>
  <div class="cd-panel-container">
    Panel 2
  </div>
</div>

<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn" id="nvv-i" data-panel="1">Show Panel 1</i><br />
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn" id="nvv-i" data-panel="2">Show Panel 2</i>
```

Comment: I think you have added 
data-panel="1"

Comment: I think that should help me with the solution. Let me quickly try it and get back. Thanks @Ant

Comment: Check out this JsFiddle using the code you provided in your question: https://jsfiddle.net/0kevddnc/

Comment: Right after `$('.showPanelButton').click(function(){` you may wish to consider adding `$('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');` to hide any previously opened panels.

Comment: But in this case both the sidepanels remain open, whereas I need the first one to close automatically when the second button is clicked and second panel should open

Comment: @Bob, I've changed the example above to use the code you've provided in the question and also addressed the issue with multiple panels being open.

Comment: Just to add:
I have panels named as

Comment: Just to add: I have panels named as 1. cd-panel 2. cd-panel-1 3. cd-panel-2 etc buttons controlling them are 1. cd-btn 2. cd-btn-1 3. cd-btn-2

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, you have 3 panels, and 3 buttons? The first panel has a class of `cd-panel` and the second has a class of `cd-panel-1`?

Comment: yes and to use them they have each assigned to their individual buttons

Comment: @Bob, you'd need to provide this code in your question. I would typically advise against the way you have it at the moment as the naming convention isn't strictly adhered to, i.e. you don't have an id on the first button, but you do on subsequent buttons. This would make it slightly more difficult (but definitely not impossible) to write a one-for-all solution.